# I added an HTML button to my page, and if you click on it, it hides the button , but I want the button to be hidden for 11 hours

Tags: html, button, timer, hide, show

```
<button type="button"
style="background-color:skyblue; border-color:blue; color:white"
className="bn49"
onClick = "this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; window.open('https://frankvanasch.com/elementor-158/','_blank')"
>go
</button>
```

Comment: I already tried to put this one in the code, but it doesn't seem to work : window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     var currentTime = new Date();
     var hours = currentTime.getHours();
     var this = document.getElementById("btn1");

    if(hours>10) {
     this.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
     this.style.display = "block";
    }
}, false);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please edit your post and add all of the information in your comment into the actual post. Please use the provided code-block feature for the code elements in the comment _ Visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' including the article on How to Ask a Good Question >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Reaching your objective with HTML and JavaScript might be impossible if you user know what they are doing.

If you want to hide the button for 11 hours, I'd use `localStorage` or a cookie to store its status, and to choose if you want to show the button.
And invert the logic, like the button must be hidden by default, and shown only if no interaction has been made, or if the last interaction was more than 11 hours ago.

Somthing like this, of course this snippet cannot run here because of SO localStorage restrictions.

```js
$(".bn49").on("click", function(evt) {
  let tgt = evt.target;
  $(tgt).hide();
  localStorage.setItem("bn49", new Date().toISOString());
  window.open('https://frankvanasch.com/elementor-158/', '_blank');
});

$(function() {
  let btnTime = localStorage.getItem("bn49");
  if (btnTime) {
    // there is a time stored, we'll check it
    let t = new Date();
    t.setHours(t.getHours() - 11);
    if (new Date(btnTime).getTime() > t.getTime()) {
      // 11 hours have passed, show the button
      $(".bn49").show();
    }
  } else {
    // there isn't a time stored, show the button
    $(".bn49").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" style="background-color:skyblue; border-color:blue; color:white; visibility: hidden;" className="bn49">go</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. but that isn't html code right ? .. probably a stupid question .. but I only started to try coding in HTML .. if I put the "big" code from above in my html page. it just shows the code.. it doesn't show any button.

Comment: @FrankVanAsch correct, it's javascript code, even further, it's javascript code using a javascript library (jQuery).
The thing you want to do is not doable by HTML only, and you already used some javascript in your "onClick" event.
To make my version work you just have to put the JS code inside a <script> tag, and include the jquery library as it does in the example.

Comment: oh ok .. theank you very much .. that did it :-)